# Schema.org for portfolio homepage

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am building a portfolio home for a friend of mine. He is an artist and his homepage should include a lot of interactive elements, so I decided to build it using React. However, this implies that the overall markup of the page will be nearly empty on load and I would like to include JSON-LD formatted data to regain search engines' attention.

So within the `index.html` file I have this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "author": { … }
  …
}
</script>
```

But is this the right `@type`, would `Person` be more accurate here? I even stumbled over the [`EntryPoint`](https://schema.org/EntryPoint) schema, which as well seams to be good because the main index is indeed the »Entrypoint« from the programs point of view.

Comment: Where is `imprint` coming from?

Comment: right now from a file…

Comment: I mean the `imprint` property you used in your JSON-LD. Given the @context, it should be [`http://schema.org/imprint`](https://schema.org/imprint), but this isn’t a Schema.org property (404 error).

Comment: That is what I am asking for. the `imprint` is a link to a »child page«, like a menu item on a webpage. How can I markup that? does it have to be like `'imprint': { '@type': 'WebPage', '@id': '<some url'' }` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, each entity can be represented with Schema.org, not just one. You don’t have to decide whether to use `WebPage` *or* `Person`, you can use both.

But this is what your snippet shows anyway, as the value for the [`author`](https://schema.org/author) property would (ideally) be a `Person` item. This `Person` could also be the value of other properties, like [`about`](https://schema.org/about)/[`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity), [`publisher`](https://schema.org/publisher) etc.

For the semantics of the data, it’s irrelevant which entity is the top-level item in the JSON-LD, if that is what you’re asking.

The `EntryPoint` type is not suitable, as it’s intended for protocols/APIs/etc., not just any webpage/website.